# What means the "M5" or "M6" in Maven Version exactly?

Tags: java, maven

I would like to use a Java library ([SpringBoot](http://start.spring.io/)) in latest version (2.0.0.M6), but I prefer to use only releases. So what means this "M6" in the library version? Is it a pre-release?

Thanks!

Comment: They're [milestones](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes), it's not a release but a pre-release version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a Milestone release.  The version includes some set of functionality that were released as soon as that set of functionality was complete.

In some organizations, this is considered pre-alpha software, where an alpha release is the first phase to start white-box, and possibly black-box or grey-box testing techniques.

Since these milestones have a number associated with it, this is the sixth milestone.  What that means is entirely dependent on the project, and its development / release plan.

For spring-boot specifically, they targeted the completion of these issues to state that they had "achieved" 2.0.0, Milestone 6.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestone/92?closed=1

In any case, this is pre-release software.